# How to simplify verbose WPF DataGrid Xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid with many columns (below I showed only 3 columns for simplicity). To mark up a single column it takes almost 20 lines of code and it repeats for every column. The only difference between the columns is the header text and the binding.

MainView.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="UserInterface.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:UserInterface.Converters"
        xmlns:UiUtilities="clr-namespace:.UserInterface.UIUtilities"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Icon="Application.ico"
        Title="{Binding WindowTitle}"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
        <Converters:VisibleIfOfTypeXConverter x:Key="VisibleIfOfTypeX" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataModel}" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header1">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="UserInterface:SomeType">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfOfTypeX}}">
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="P1Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                            <UiUtilities:NumberRule />
                                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    </Binding>
                                </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header2">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="UserInterface:SomeType">
                        <Grid>                          
                            <TextBox Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfOfTypeX}}">
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="P2Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                            <UiUtilities:NumberRule />
                                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    </Binding>
                                </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header3">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="UserInterface:SomeType">
                        <Grid>                                                        <TextBox Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfOfTypeX}}">
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="P3Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                            <UiUtilities:NumberRule />
                                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    </Binding>
                                </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Window>
```

I'm still a beginner in WPF, but I assume there must be a less verbose way to implement this. I imagine there must be some sort of "templating" or components as they are used in other UI Frameworks.
Could we create some sort of component (I call it "MyCustomDataGridColumn"), that we could use like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataModel}">

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <MyCustomDataGridColumn Header="Header1" TextBoxBinding="P1Text">
        <MyCustomDataGridColumn Header="Header2" TextBoxBinding="P2Text">
        <MyCustomDataGridColumn Header="Header3" TextBoxBinding="P3Text">
      
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How could we achieve this?  Or are there other/better ways to reduce verbosity?

Comment: Unfortunately, in general, there is no way to reuse a template and only replace a binding path in it. A template must be defined as a whole

Comment: Are you doing all that work just to get some validation rules for the data?  Have you considered just using data annotations on the class the data is binding to instead?

Comment: You should simply avoid defining redundant templates. In your example you would implements model validation by implementing `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. If you have simple text cells, then let the DataGrid auto-generate them. Data model validation is the preferred validation technique. Binding validation most of the time is more difficult to maintain. Prefer `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.

Comment: @BionicCode: I did already fix the validation part with `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. Thanks for that hint! But you said "You should simply avoid defining redundant templates". Well that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. But how??? Do you see how this could be done I my case?

Comment: Like I said, *"If you have simple text cells, then let the DataGrid auto-generate them."*.

Comment: I tried `DataGridTextColumn`, but it shows text as Textblock. I need it to always be displayed as Textbox. I guess to achieve this I have to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`? Or can I apply some Style to the  `DataGridTextColumn`?